# DbConnection string issue on Appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to read 5 connections strings from the same `appSettings.json` file? The project is monolithic.

Using this as one:

```
"DbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=atmwithdrawalstore;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 1):

appsettings.json

```
....
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=...",
    "Connection1": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=....",
    "Connection2": "Data Source=..."
  },
.....
```

startup.cs

```
var defaultConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var connectionString2 = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection2");
 .......           

 services.AddDbContext<DbContext2>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString2));
....
services.AddDbContext<DefaultDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionString));
```